# What rule is used to expand the following product (LHS) into the expression (RHS)?

Tags: summation, products

$\prod_{j=1}^{m} (1-e^{- r_j \cdot x}) = 1 - \Sigma_{i=1}^{m} e^{-r_i\cdot x } + \Sigma_{i=1}^{m} e^{-r_i\cdot x}\cdot \Sigma_{j>i}^{m}e^{-r_j\cdot x} - \Sigma_{i=1}^{m}e^{-r_i\cdot x}\cdot \Sigma_{j>i}^{m}e^{-r_j\cdot x} \cdot \Sigma_{k>j}^{m}e^{-r_k\cdot x} + \cdots + (-1)^m e^{-\Sigma_{i=1}^{m}r_i\cdot x}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x>0$, $0\leq A_i=e^{-r_i \cdot x} \leq 1$.

As $A$ is probability, now we can write $1-A = \bar A$. Products are analogous to intersections therefore we can write

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\prod_{i=1}^{m} P(1 - e^{-r_i \cdot x}) =\prod_{i=1}^{m} P(\bar A_i) = \bigcap_{i=1}^{m} P(\bar A_i) = 1 - \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} P(A_i) 
\end{equation}

Now we can use inclusion-exclusion principle

\begin{equation} \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} P(A)  = \Sigma_{i=1}^{m} P(A_i) - \Sigma_{1\leq i < j \leq m} P(A_i \cap A_j) + \cdots + (-1)^m (A_i \cap A_{i+1} \cap \cdots \cap A_m) \end{equation}

We convert intersections back to products

\begin{equation} \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} P(A)  = \Sigma_{i=1}^{m} P(A_i) - \Sigma_{i= 1}^{m}P(A_i)\cdot\Sigma_{j>i}^ {m} P(A_j) + \cdots + (-1)^m P(A_i)\cdot P(A_{i+1})  \cdots P(A_m) \end{equation}

Insert values of $Ai$s, i.e., $A_i=e^{-r_i \cdot x}$

\begin{equation} \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} P(A)  = \Sigma_{i=1}^{m} e^{-r_i \cdot x} - \Sigma_{i= 1}^{m}e^{-r_i \cdot x} \cdot\Sigma_{j>i}^ {m} e^{-r_j \cdot x} + \cdots + (-1)^m e^{-r_i \cdot x}\cdot e^{-r_{i+1} \cdot x}  \cdots e^{-r_m \cdot x}\end{equation}

Further simplification yield

\begin{equation} \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} P(A)  = \Sigma_{i=1}^{m} e^{-r_i \cdot x} - \Sigma_{i= 1}^{m}e^{-r_i \cdot x} \cdot \Sigma_{j>i}^{m} e^{-r_j \cdot x} + \cdots + (-1)^m e^{-\Sigma_{i=1}^{m}{r_i \cdot x}} \end{equation}

Put this equation back into (1) we get
\begin{equation} 
\prod_{i=1}^{m}(1-e^{r_i\cdot x})  = 1 - \Sigma_{i=1}^{m} e^{-r_i \cdot x} - \Sigma_{i= 1}^{m}e^{-r_i \cdot x} \cdot \Sigma_{j>i}^{m} e^{-r_j \cdot x} + \cdots + (-1)^m e^{-\Sigma_{i=1}^{m}{r_i \cdot x}} \end{equation}

Comment: I include my solution to solicit feedback.

Comment: I think this shows that you understand what's going on. Except you have typo in the $(-1)^m$ (note the bracket).

Comment: Typo corrected. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion.

We can solve this by making an analog with probability theory.

Since multiplication is analogous to $\cap$, and addition/subtraction is analogous to inclusion/exclusion, we might as well be finding:

$$|\bigcap_{j=1}^m (X - A_j)|,$$

where $X$ is the universal set.

Now, to see the right hand side, we can tentatively include $|X|$, but we have overcounted, so we can take away the sum of $|A_j|$, getting

$$|X|  - \sum_{j=1}^m |A_j|.$$

However, we have oversubtracted those elements that are in two or more of the $A_j$’s, so we add them back. Iteratively, we get that the right hand side should be:

$$|X| - \sum_{j=1}^m |A_j| + \bigg(\sum_{j=1}^m |A_j|\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^m |A_k| \bigg)- \ldots + (-1)^m \underbrace{\sum \cdots \sum |A_{\cdots}|}_{\prod_{i=1}^m |A_i|}.$$

Now, converting back to your equation means that the right hand side now makes sense.

Comment: Which software can help solving such equations step by step?

Comment: It’s unclear what you mean. But the wikipedia article is a very good reference in this case https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle

Comment: Towards the end, you have $\prod$ (see underbrace) but I'm my expression it is $\Sigma$. I have more such expressions to solve. Maybe a reference to relevant text will also be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you have a sum in the exponent, and that is the same as a product outside the exponent, because $e^{A+B}=e^A \times e^B$